# Error message after updating Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: updates, 22.04

I installed ubuntu Today. After installing ubuntu 22.04 and I go for update from **Software Updater**

I faced following error message when installing update:
**The application Passwords and Keys has closed unexpectedly**

1. What should I do now?
2. Is it security problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was solved if I disabled the app search of "Password and Keys" under Settings -> Search.

For some reason it is checked by default and I wonder why it is there, as I'd not want application search in that app when pressing the Windows key...